# Ambassador Host {hostname}: invalid TLS secret ssl-cert, marking inactive

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, ambassador

I am using the Ambassador in my GKE cluster. I am getting below issue but I am having valid ssl certificate as secret in my configuration.

**Secret myapp-ssl-cert.ambassadorpoc unknown 

Host myapp: invalid TLS secret myapp-ssl-cert, marking inactive**

My host yaml file looks like below:

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Host
metadata:
    name: myapp
    namespace: ambassadorpoc
spec:
    hostname: '*'
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            hostname: myapp
    acmeProvider:
        authority: none
    tlsSecret:
        name: myapp-ssl-cert
    requestPolicy:
        insecure:
            action: Redirect
            additionalPort: 8080
```

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Based on [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/howtos/tls-termination/#tell-productname-to-use-this-secret-for-tls-termination) yaml looks correct. Is secret in the same namespace? I also see `edge stack` should be installed.

Comment: @moonkotte edge-stack, edge-stack-admin and edge-stack-redis all three were installed. But it is not taking the secret. the secret also created in same namesapce.

Comment: How did you create the `myapp-ssl-cert` tlsSecret?

Comment: I have followed steps provided the below link for creating the secret.  https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/howtos/tls-termination/#:~:text=TLS%20encryption%20is%20one%20of%20the%20basic%20requirements,termination%20for%20all%20of%20your%20services%20in%20Kubernetes.

Comment: Pls add `kubectl describe` of your secret to the post. 
What AES version are you using?

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova I have attached the screenshot for the describe cmd and I am using the latest version

Comment: Can you try adding a `ambassador_id` filed to your Host spec?

Comment: @GariSingh, When I add the ambassador_id, cert not found error is not coming and ambassador still not working. In the envoy.json file I am not able to find the TLS details.

Comment: I found the issue. There is a problem with the listener configured. Now it is working fine. But I am not able to access the admin console "/edge_stack/admin" path.

Comment: @SooryaPrakash I'm currently experiencing the same problem. 
Can you elaborate what has been the issue with you listener ?